# How to install Magento PWA Studio on DigitalOcean?

Tags: pwa-studio

I have an installed & working Magento 2.4.1 on a DigitalOcean server and trying to install a PWA Studio on top of it (on the same server).

Currently, the PWA Studio is somehow installed by following this (https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/) guide but it’s not working properly.

I also installed UPWARD connector together with UPWARD-PHP and configured it in admin panel and now on some pages I see the following error: {"error":"No definition for veniaResponse.status"}.

You can access the site here: 46.101.96.222.

Can you help or share a step-by-step guide on how to install it on DigitalOcean?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After setup your backend URL (46.101.96.222) in PWA-Studio run the following in the root folder:

```
npm run build && NODE_ENV=production PORT=8000 npm run stage:venia
```

It will start the server on port 8000.

you can use [process manager 2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) (PM2)  for managing node services.

```
cd packages/venia-concept/ && NODE_ENV=production PORT=8000 node server.js
```

Then create a proxy to pass connection from 8000 to 80 and 443